# NameError: name 'app' is not defined

Tags: python, api, flask, flask-restful

When i run app__init__.py got this error, but could not understand why?i am new to python and flask, please help!!!

**file structure**

```
app\ resource\
         __init__.py
         rest3_product.py
__init__.py
```

**app\ __init__.py**

```
from flask import Flask
from flask_restful import Resource, Api

def create_app (config_name='development') :
    app = Flask(__name__)
    api = Api(app)

    from resource.rest3_product import rest3_product

    api.add_resource(plyPosition, "/plyPosition")

    initialize_extensions(app)
    return app

if__name__== '___main___':
    app.run(port=8000, debug = True)
```

**"rest3_product.py" is**

```
from flask import Flask

from flask_restful import Api, Resource, reqparse




class plyPosition(Resource):

  def post(self):
     parser = reqparse.RequestParser(bundle_errors= True)

     parser.add_argument("productId", required=True, type= int)
     parser.add_argument("productCatId", required= True, type= int)
     parser.add_argument("measureUniId", required= True, type= int)
     parser.add_argument("productName", required= True, type= str)
     parser.add_argument("length", required= True, type= int)
     parser.add_argument("breadth", required= True, type= int)
     parser.add_argument("height", required= True, type= int)
     parser.add_argument("createdAt", required= True, type= int)
     parser.add_argument("updatedAt", required= True, type= int)

     try:
         args = parser.parse_args()
     except Exception:
         return "Please Check Your Request!!!!!!!!!"

     return args
```

Answer (score 2):

`create_app()` instantiate a Flask instance, it's your `app`. So you need to call `create_app()` first, store the returned instance in a variable and then use this variable

```
if __name__ == '___main___':
    app = create_app()
    app.run(port=8000, debug = True)
```